# With 10 entries in a big random draw, what is the probability of getting exactly x prizes?

Tags: probability

Me and my friends are going to Kiev later this month for European football's Champions League final.

We are Liverpool fans and have entered the club's ballot for tickets.

We have 10 entries in the ballot, and we know (announced by the club) that each individual has an approximately 1 in 3.7 shot at getting a ticket, from 25,578 ballot registrations (i.e. approximately 6,913 available tickets).

The draw is random, overseen by independent adjudicators. Each fan can obviously only win once, and once they have been drawn out as a winner they are not returned to the pile of registrations.

Working out $ 1- \frac{\binom{25568}{6913}}{\binom{25578}{6913}} $ I know that between us the probability of getting at least one ticket is 0.957211108.

But I don't know how we'd work out the probability of getting ***exactly*** $x$ tickets in the ballot between us, where $x$ is 2, 3, 4 etc.

I obviously get that the probability of two of us getting tickets, individually, would be $ \left(\frac{6913}{25578}\right)\times\left(\frac{6912}{25577}\right) $, but is that the same when we're talking about two tickets from our pool of ten in general?

Many thanks!

Comment: Check out the Binomial Distribution Formula.

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore the fact that one draw succeeding reduces the chance the next one does, which is reasonable with this many tickets and draws, each draw is an independent event with chance of success $\frac 1{3.7}$  The chance of getting $x$ tickets is then $${10 \choose x} \left(\frac 1{3.7}\right)^x\left(\frac {2.7}{3.7}\right)^{(10-x)}$$
from the [Binomial distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)